# Fullscreen in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I work with Flash Adobe CS6.

I want to have a fullscreenmode in my application. In AC2 there was a function fscommand. I tried this one, but without success. I just have a .swf file, which should go to fullscreenmode after starting.

Do i have a opportunity to bring my application in Fullscreen Mode, without using Adobe Air ?

Flash Player Version: 11.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
```

Answer (score 5):

Use either

`stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` (You need to target FP 11.3+ to use this mode)

or

`stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`.

The latter one won't allow you to read keyboard input while in full-screen mode.

Comment: StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE also available in AIR 1.0+ :)

Answer (score 0):

First put an MC on your stage and Instance Name is toggle, then
you might use this one:

```
var fullScreen:Boolean = false;
toggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleScreen);

function toggleScreen(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(fullScreen == false)
   {
        fullScreen = true;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
   }
   else
   {
        fullScreen = false;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL; 
   }

}
```